# How can I add a custom string to jQuery .css() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to pass in a custom string to the .css jQuery function. So instead of doing this:

```
$('#image1').css('background', 'url("img1.png") no-repeat');
```

I want to do this:

```
var image = "'url(\"img1.png\") no-reapt'"
$('#image1').css('background', image);
```

But it's not working. The reason I want to do it like that is because I have 6 elements with 6 different possibilities of different images so I want to add them dynamically. So it would actually look more like this, my variable:

```
var image = "'url(\"" + this.image.imgs[value[i]] + "\") no-repeat'"
$('#image1').css('background', image);
```

And it would be inside a loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the extra `''` symbols. You don't need them. In your string, which is a css style - `''` symbols are not valid and they cause not to apply the style.

```
var image = "url(\"img1.png\") no-repeat";
$('#image1').css('background', image);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing your single quotes. Like so.

```
var image = "url(\"img1.png\") no-repeat";
$('#image1').css('background', image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove single quotes and if you want to add **multiple css property**, you have to use like :

```
var image = "url(\"" + this.image.imgs[value[i]] + "\") no-repeat";
$('#image1').css({'background': image,'border': '1px solid'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = "url('img1.png') no-repeat";
$('#image1').css('background', image);
```

you can  try  this you have missed a semicolon  and misplaced `'`&`"`